# Eloquent Query With Custom Method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am using laravel 7 eloquent. i am very new to laravel

this is basic method i am getting data from `category` table

```
public function category(){

    $category = Category::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    
    $data['pageData'] = $category;
    $data['pageTitle'] = "Category";
    
    return view('admin.category.index')->with('data',$data);
}
```

But i want to do something like this

```
public function category(){

    $category = Category::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['parent_id']))
        $category->where('parent_id',$_REQUEST['parent_id']);

    $data['pageData'] = $category;
    $data['pageTitle'] = "Category";
    
    return view('admin.category.index')->with('data',$data);
}
```

So how can this is possible using eloquent.
Any help out of this question are helpful for me as i am beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function category(){
    
    $query = Category::orderBy('id','desc');
    $query = where('parent_id',$_REQUEST['parent_id']);

    $category = $query->get();

    $data['pageData'] = $category;
    $data['pageTitle'] = 'Category';

    return view('admin.category.index')->with('data',$data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the `when()` eloquent method to add conditional clause to query:

```
 public function category()
        {
            $category = Category::when(request('parent_id'),function($parent_id,$query)
            {
                $query->where('parent_id',$parent_id);
            })->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    
            $data['pageData'] = $category;
            $data['pageTitle'] = "Category";
    
            return view('admin.category.index')->with('data',$data);
       }
```

`when()` doc reference  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `when` method to only apply the query if the request contains the `parent_id`.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses):

> Sometimes you may want certain query clauses to apply to a query based
> on another condition. For instance, you may only want to apply a `where`
> statement if a given input value is present on the incoming HTTP
> request. You may accomplish this using the `when` method:

```
$role = $request->input('role');

$users = DB::table('users')
    ->when($role, function ($query, $role) {
        return $query->where('role_id', $role);
    })
    ->get();
```

> The `when` method only executes the given closure when the first
> argument is `true`. If the first argument is `false`, the closure will not
> be executed. So, in the example above, the closure given to the `when`
> method will only be invoked if the `role` field is present on the
> incoming request and evaluates to `true`.

In your case it would be the following:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;  

public function category(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::query()
        ->when($request->input('parent_id'), function ($query, $parent_id) {
            $query->where('parent_id', $parent_id);
        })
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->get();

    $data['pageData'] = $categories;
    $data['pageTitle'] = "Category";

    return view('admin.category.index')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: Is it good to use eloquent here or to use DB query Builder here ? because i've many parameters to filter data upon form request

Comment: @Carlos Yes you should use eloquent here, the docs just use the query builder to simplify the example.

Comment: @Remul there is an error in you response, the first param to the `when()` will be the `$parent_id` and not the `$query`. Also please note that calling the builder with `Category::query()` is not necessary. You can directly call `Category::when()` as i suggested bellow

Comment: @Remul But what if i have multiple parameters to filter like more than 5

Comment: @ml59 You can see from the docs that it is `function ($query, $role)`, not the other way around. I know that `query()` is not needed, but in this case it lets you structure the code better so every statement can be put on its own line (personal preference).

Comment: @Carlos you can use as many `when()`  as you'd like, but it probably depends on how you want to filter it.

Comment: @Remul That's just an ide settings. Calling the Builder here is unecessary but anyways

Answer (score 0):

You can do as like below

```
public function category(){

   $category = new Category();

  if(!empty($_REQUEST['parent_id'])){
     $category->where('parent_id',$_REQUEST['parent_id']);
  }

  $category = $category->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get()


  $data['pageData'] = $category;
  $data['pageTitle'] = "Category";

  return view('admin.category.index')->with('data',$data);
}
```

Comment: i tried your method but it wont working. https://prnt.sc/w35yqf

Answer (score 0):

Try using laravel when condition
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: Question is about the using eloquent not DB Query Builder

Comment: But in code he has explained that he want to achieve conditional query based on request param. if there is a request param then and only apply condition.

Answer (score 0):

Improve your question with proper details. as you mention in the question the second coding path won't work because it doesn't have `$request` query to functionally run the if statement. anyhow if you want to get only `pageData & pageTitle` in laravel Eloquent ORM you have to select both columns as follows.

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function category(){
        $category = Category::select('pageData', 'pageTitle')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
        return view('admin.category.index')->with('data', $category);
    }
}
```